# What's wrong in directly using tikzcd environment?

Tags: errors, tikz-cd

I have a MikTeX 2.9 distribution installed on Windows 7 with PGF 2.10 and tikz and I get a hundred errors at compilation no matter how many dollar sings I use to surround the diagram environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{tikzcd}
0
\end{tikzcd}$$
\end{document}
```

Upon compilation, I get `missing dollar inserted`, then `missing } inserted`, then `giving up on this path; did you forget a semicolon?`, `missing }`, `missing endgroup" and after that kind of 90 "misplaced \cr`. Even more, lots of `generic\pgf` files seem to be loaded. As I said, I tried removing the dollar signs; to no avail.

I mention that tikz-cd diagrams worked very well until now, but they've surely done something with this update. Some files were downloaded today, before I decided to show you this "minimal file", and with the ridiculous "documentation" on this project's site I can't do anything but ask for help.

Comment: Your code compiles okay using `pdflatex` on my system (same as yours).

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$$...$$`, but rather `\[...\]`; but other than that I don't see any reason for strange errors.

Comment: Here is a link related to egreg's comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Thank you; @Kevin C: That's what I said; the tikzcd environments used to compile on my system too, but now with some new version of it they don't anymore. I tried to reinstall, but it didn't help; I'll try on some other laptop, anyway thanks for everything.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, you might delete it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some localized issue. The problem is not reproducible.